# Matter transportation or housing for Cosmic string information FTL

Tags: gravity, transportation

An advanced future empire uses cosmic strings as FTL to transport information around the empires network of strings, they use this method also to materialise their robotic bodies and minds in far off locations to fulfil tasks that need material bodies.

A collection of necessary materials is housed near the cosmic string ends to manufacture transported beings but in the case of a major war, can an army of quadrillions of ships and warriors be assembled in time?

This is not an issue of the speed of the manufacturing process but an issue of the distance to collect materials and house enough in a close enough space that does not create a blackhole.

My question is can a cosmic string be used to transport vast amounts of matter and if not how does the empire manage the matter issue at the manufacturing ends of the cosmic strings when large amounts of matter are needed?

Comment: It isn't readily apparent that cosmic strings can be used for FTL travel or signalling _at all_. As much, you've basically created your own magical handwavium and called it "cosmic strings", and you may choose whatever properties you'd like for it. We might be able to do some kind of reality check for you, if you were able to describe the properties of your strings in at least some kind of detail.

Comment: But it is known that Cosmic strings can transport electromagnetism at the speed of light and I have embellished that for my story based of VSL theory. A kink on the string from a loop cut off can propagate along the string at the speed of light, this could carry matter, but only at speed of light.

Comment: If we assume the cosmic string contains a higher energy topology which allows the FTL the civilization uses, but the diameter of the string is thousands below a protons diameter, the actual diameter or radius of something so theoretical is up for debate, but if quarks could be sent down it is another issue, so matter being sent down it is up for speculation but theorise state a current can be sent through a string.

Comment: I did not think I needed to state the properties of a cosmic string for the question to be answerable, its electromagnetic properties are exaggerated for the story but the rest of its properties can be based in the same way.

Comment: The truth is there is no science to answer your question, you can make up any limits that you want. No one else can create a story that is only imagined. I know this is your first visit, please read [this post on how to write good questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question), and I'm sure this can be edited to fit the Worldbuilding site.

Comment: If I had stated that it was another method of information FTL then member could have easily answered this, I don't see why this question is causing trouble.

Comment: We don't even know if cosmic strings exist. And if they do, we don't know that it is possible to use them in such a way. The constants of nature could change near one.  The charge on electrons, the mass of atoms, nuclear reaction rates, all could change drastically. You could de-rez if you got close enough to use any supposed FTL.

Comment: Agree with Starfish Prime's comment here. Your cosmic strings are not dependent on existing scientific insights. Just see you make them behave in your story, as your story requires. Look at the sources for terminology, to let it all sound plausible (no one understands cosmic strings anyway)

Comment: @JarredJones It sounds like the cosmic strings are not important to the question at all. You have some magical science pipeline that you can shoot matter down and reassemble it at the end. And you ask about the logistics of feeding a lot of matter down one end.

Comment: Without knowing what the required mass any individual ship or warrior, we can't guess at the mass for "quadrillions" of them and whether that would result in a black hole, although given the statement that "speed of manufacturing is not an issue", it seems trivial to spread the feedstock masses at the destination out as much as required.  This seems separate to the final question asking "Can <magic> break the laws of physics, if not what is some alternative magic?" - one question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cosmic Spiderweb**

[image]

The empire spans the galaxy. The Cosmic Strings span the galaxy. You can hop onto the cosmic spiderweb at any point and travel to any other point.

The empire does not have a single huge central matter repository. This would cause cause structural problems due to gravity. Instead there are billions of smaller repositories all along the web. When forces are needed somewhere, matter is requested and sent from many repositories at once.

The matter is reassembled in several places at once too, since a billion spaceships appearing in the same place will cause trouble for each other.

**Note:** How the cosmic strings work is not important to the question at all. The question is about the logistics of a magical science FTL pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

**Science**

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_string) article on Cosmic string tells about the dimensions as follows:

> Cosmic strings, if they exist, would be extremely thin with diameters
> of the same order of magnitude as that of a proton, i.e. ~ 1 fm, or
> smaller.
>
> In field theory, the string width is set by the scale of the symmetry
> breaking phase transition. In string theory, the string width is set
> (in the simplest cases) by the fundamental string scale, warp factors
> (associated to the spacetime curvature of an internal six-dimensional
> spacetime manifold) and/or the size of internal compact dimensions.

**Story**

For the purpose of story, you can get some help [here](https://endlessspace.fandom.com/wiki/Travel_Mechanics). Cosmic string are used to transport ships.

[image]